# How can I route local network behind a client through WireGuard?

Tags: wireguard

I have a WireGuard server with local subnet 192.168.9.0/24 behind it. And a client with local subnet 192.168.4.0/24 behind it. Both running Ubuntu 22.04.

Server config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 192.168.1.1/24
SaveConfig = true
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = YYY

[Peer]
PublicKey = XXX
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.2/32
```

Client config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = WWW
Address = 192.168.1.2

[Peer]
PublicKey = QQQQ
AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.0/24, 192.168.9.0/24
Endpoint = PUBLIC_IP:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

My client is able to access the 192.168.9.0/24 subnet that is behind my server but my server isn´t able to access the 192.168.4.0/24 subnet behind my client.

How can I make my server access the 192.168.4.0/24 subnet behind my client?

Can these change take place only when the client connects to the server and not when WireGuard starts in the server?

Update 1:

Consider that the server and the client are the default gateways on their respective subnets.

Also consider that the traffic leaving the server and the client are natted to the server and client local IPs when leaving both on the VPN interface and on the local subnets.

Comment: Without NAT all systems (eg: nodes on 192.168.4.0/24) must know the adequate route through the adequate router (eg: the client) to reach the other networks. If you configured NAT along other settings you should also state it.

Comment: Routing in a private network is a single routing domain and doesn't use NAT. Also, you'd use a wireguard *router* instead of a client on that end.

Comment: @Zac67  I don't understand how your comment applies to my issue. Can you better explain or give examples?

Comment: your server peer config states `AllowedIPs = 192.168.1.2/32` ... so why would the server know to use the peer to access `192.168.4.0` - another thing, I beleive the clients interface should have `Address = 192.168.1.2/24` not `Address = 192.168.1.2` - though perhaps the `/24` is implied. I've never relied on implied values though

Comment: @Rsevero In order to connect two *networks* you'd use *two servers*, not a server and a client. Also, you generally don't NAT between private networks, only between public and private networks (or more generally, between different address domains).